# Ошибка при запуске telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('823871901:AAFrwDCr2ettFfqpmHQZhyQtMcX5d-_lGhE')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def handle_start(message): 
user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False) 
user_markup.row('start') 
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Асуждаю', reply_markup=user_markup

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Ошибка:
File "bot.py", line 9
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Вы в строчке

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Асуждаю', reply_markup=user_markup
```

забыли закрывающую скобку в конце.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь